# POSTGRES - Sub Query returns the result very Slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I've a fairly simple query, but it includes a Sub - Query. 
I want to fetch list of `resource_id` which pass through a filter in `ORDER BY DESC;` order.

**MORE INFORMATION**
Basically we need to find the list of `resource_id's` which pass through a filter mentioned in the query below,

```
   SELECT rs.resource_id
FROM resource rs
WHERE (
    SELECT rc.resource_id
    FROM risk_child rc
    WHERE rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id 
    AND rc.cloudaccount_id = rs.cloud_account_id
    AND rs.reg_id= any(array[236]) 
    AND rc.risk_level= any(array['high','low'])
    AND rc.status = any(array['fail'])
    AND rc.cloudaccount_id= any (array['4ZiCmwslbjhmRtHAOjLG'])
    ORDER BY rc.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) = rs.resource_id
```

these resources would then be passed into another query as mentioned here:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (rc.resource_id, rc.rule_id, s.id) MAX(rc.creationtime) as creationtime,
  rc.resource_id,
  rl.rule_tag,
  s.service,
  r.region,
  rc.status,
  rs.vpc_id,
  rc.cloudaccount_id,
  rc.organization_id,
  rs.owner_id,
  rc.description,
  f.function_name,
  g.group_name,
  rc.risk_level,
  rc.id,
  rc.user_id,
  rc.pro_id,
  c.category_name,
  rc.raw as rawResponse,
  rs.res_ca_id,
  rs.resource_name
FROM
  risk_child rc,
  resource rs,
  rule rl,
  service s,
  region r,
  function f,
  g_by g,
  category c
WHERE
  rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id
  AND rl.id = rc.rule_id
  AND s.id = rs.ser_id
  AND rs.reg_id = r.id
  AND f.id = rc.function_id
  AND c.id = rc.category_id
  AND g.id = rc.group_id
  AND rc.cloudaccount_id like any (array $ { modifiedCloudAccounts })
  AND rc.organization_id = $ { orgId }
  AND rc.rule_id > 0
  AND rc.cloudaccount_id = rs.cloud_account_id
  AND rs.resource_id like any (array $ { getResources }) $ { risk }
GROUP BY
  rc.rule_id,
  rc.creationtime,
  rc.creationtime,
  rc.resource_id,
  rl.rule_tag,
  rl.id,
  s.service,
  r.region,
  rc.status,
  rs.vpc_id,
  rc.cloudaccount_id,
  rc.organization_id,
  rs.owner_id,
  rc.description,
  f.function_name,
  g.group_name,
  rc.risk_level,
  rc.id,
  rc.user_id,
  rc.pro_id,
  c.category_name,
  rc.raw,
  s.id,
  rs.res_ca_id
ORDER BY
  rc.resource_id,
  rc.rule_id ASC;
```

**PROBLEM**
Now the first query returns the result very slow, even after indexing the result comes in 5 - 6 seconds. So keeping in mind the first query needs to run two times

1. One to get total number of Rows (For pagination)
2. Second time to get the resource_ids

I've mainly used NO - SQL for my apps so I am fairly new to SQL querying. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: `distinct on ()` **and** `group by` looks quite strange.  Not performance relevant, but you should really avoid those old, ancient and fragile implicit joins and use  "modern" (nearly 30 years old) explicit JOIN operators.

Comment: I know the second query sucks, as I explained my background isn't from SQL. So I am bad at it, but the second query does return results fairly quick like around 1 - 2 seconds which works well with our scenario, the problem is the first one.

Comment: What is the relation between those two queries? Do you need to combine them? I think the second one can be simplified to this: http://dpaste.com/1DYBGNT

Comment: Actually the first one gives us a list of `resource_id`s which are then passed to the second query, they're not connected but run one after the other. 
The main result comes from the second query.

Comment: I am also open to the idea of not using a Sub - query to get the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand how they are combined. The first one finds resource where rows exists in risk_child. The second one then joins risk_child to resources using limiting them (I assume) through `AND rs.resource_id like any (array ${getResources})`. Why would the first one be needed to begin with, can't you just put the query conditions into the second one directly?

Comment: actually `rs.resource_id like any (array ${getResources})` this would have the resource ids where we want the result for. 
Basically each user has multiple resources, and each resource goes through multiple filters. So we only need those resource_ids which have those filters to do the following
1 - Pagination
2 - Get first 10 resources on a single page by adding `LIMIT 10 OFFSET `

Comment: Something like this: http://dpaste.com/2HXFCV0

Comment: `resource` table is a list of resources
`risk_child` is a list of risk items that are associated with those resources. 
We have a table on the front end that structures like this:

Resource
-- Risk
-- Risk
-- Risk
Resource 
-- Risk
-- Risk

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2HXFCV0 would only give us `Risks` which are associated to all resources, but we need to add pagination to limit to only 10 resources which can't be done here.

Comment: @SumairBaloch . . . I think you should ask a *new* question.  Focus only on the first query.  Explain the logic you are trying to implement -- things such as the `limit 1` in the subquery.  Sample data and desired results  would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally this thing worked for my case:

```
    SELECT rs.resource_id
FROM resource rs
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM risk_child rc
              WHERE rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id 
                AND rc.cloudaccount_id = rs.cloud_account_id
                AND rs.reg_id= any(array[236]) 
                AND rc.risk_level= any(array['high','low'])
                AND rc.status = any(array['fail'])
                AND rc.cloudaccount_id= any (array['4ZiCmwslbjhmRtHAOjLG'])
             )
```

Basically as I had explained this in my post I am fairly new to SQL, I didn't put proper indexing in my tables so I had to add the following indexes to make the query faster

`resource(resource_id, cloud_account_id)` and `risk_child(resource_id, cloudaccount_id)` this helped me improve my performance even more.

Comment: Since you have solved this question by yourself, You should better delete this question then.

Comment: Shouldn't I leave it here so other people can get help from it ?